# How to stay a chrome extension remain open after escape button press

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have made a chrome extension.There I have a text box which can be hide and show.I can write something in that text box.When I press the task extension is closed. But what I looking for that pressing escape should not close the extension but hide the text box.I can hide the text box by pressing the escape button. But how to stop closing the extension.Please help

Comment: You're looking for `preventDefault()`.

Comment: I am looking for how to stop closing the extension when escape button is pressed

Comment: That's what `preventDefault()` does.

Comment: $('body').keypress(function(e){
    alert(e.which);
    if(e.which == 27){
        preventDefault();
    }
});

i used the code.but did not work.. it gives alert all key except escape. When I press escape it close the extension

Comment: you need `keydown`, not `keypress`.

Comment: Thanks. Its working.